# How to show/hide "printer-friendly version" link according to workflow states?

Tags: 7, theming, workflows

There's a review content type on my site with a workflow: I use '**draft**' and '**completed**' workflow states.

I'd like to create a printer-friendly and pdf-version of '**finished**' reviews only, so I'd like to hide the links generated by [Print module](https://www.drupal.org/project/print) in any other case.
I tried to modify `MYTHEME__preprocess_node()` to achive this with this code, but it didn't work:

```
if($vars['field_review_workflow'][0]['value'] == '13'){ //sid of 'finished' state
  show($vars['elements']['links']['print_html']);
}else{
  hide($vars['elements']['links']['print_html']);
}
```

How could I do it properly?

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it is by using [hook_node_view_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7). For example, you would put the following code in a custom module called `hideprint` (see many tutorials online on how to create a custom module). **Be sure** to `dpm()` the array `$build` when you are testing the module to correctly check the value of field_review_workflow.

```
function hideprint_node_view_alter(&$build) {
  if ($build['field_review_workflow'][0]['#value'] == TYPE_VALUE_FOR_NOT_FINISHED){
    hide($build['links']['print_html']);
    hide($build['links']['print_pdf']);
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a module for that! [Workflow Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/workflow_fields)

> This module extends Workflow by allowing CCK node fields to be made
>   invisible or read-only depending on the current workflow state. The
>   workflow state form is extended to show all node fields with
>   appropriate controls to hide and/or disable each field for that
>   particular state.
>
> This functionality is useful when a workflow moves among users who
>   have different permissions regarding the document flowing through
>   them. Which is the case in most every workflow we've encountered.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not a CCK field. The [Print module](https://www.drupal.org/project/print) adds links below the contet area.

Comment: In that case you can use computed_field module and manually render print in a CCK field to be able to use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

After all, my approach has been proved to be useful too. Hiding of these links can be done in `MYTHEME_preprocess_node()` but `content` array should be used:

```
if($vars['field_review_workflow'][0]['value'] == '13'){ //sid of 'finished' state
  show($vars['content']['links']['print_html']);
}else{
  hide($vars['content']['links']['print_html']);
}
```

Anyways, thank you all for the input.